# Can I mount ext4 without writing the last mountpoint to the filesystem?

Tags: mount, ext4, readonly, read-write

I have an old `ext4` disk partition that I have to investigate without disturbing it. So I copied the complete partition to an image file and mounted that image file while continuing my investigation.

Now while I do not write to the mounted filesystem, I do have to mount it with read/write access, because one of the programs makes assumptions on what I intend to do, and requires write access, even though I do not intend to write to it. You know the kind of 'smart' programs.

Now the problem is that, when mounting an ext4 filesystem read/write, the last mount point is written into the filesystem itself, i.e. the mount command changes my image file, including file access time and file modification time. That is annoying for a lot of other reasons. I cannot find an option in [`mount(8)`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) nor in [`ext4(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html) to avoid this.

Is there another way to mount with read/write access, without the mount command writing to the filesystem?

Comment: I don't have enough practical experience with it to properly suggest it, but [OverlayFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OverlayFS) could be useful to put a writeable separate layer over your image file.

Comment: I don't know about the "write the last mount point" issue, but the `lazytime` option should at least inhibit the on-disk update of `atime/mtime/ctime`.

Comment: This isn’t all that helpful, but on Ext4, the mount point is stored the first time a file is *opened* in a file system, not when the file system is mounted.

Comment: @AdminBee I use the noatime mount option; mtime and ctime won't change as long as I don't create or modify files, I guess.

Comment: @StephenKitt Not immediately helpfull, but interesting.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Good thinking. First I dismissed it, because I do not want to write to the filesystem at all. But now I understand your trick; it just serves to trick that one program into thinking it has a writeable file system. I tested it (with unionfs-fuse instead), and the mountpoint is indeed NOT written to the image file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @UlrichSchwarz mount it read-only, then use overlayFS  or unionFS to create a writeable file-system. You can make the writable layer (the bit where the modifications go, disposable, or persistent. Ether way the changes are not stored on the master file-system.